# missing `subfigure.sty'

Tags: latex

I install texstudio by download `texstudio-qt4_2.12.14-1_amd64.deb` on ubuntu16.04, but I get this erros:

```
File `subfigure.sty' not found. \RequirePackage
```

I download subfigure from *https://ctan.org/pkg/subfigure* and make and move  it to `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex` but still not working, how to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

TeX maintains an internal TeX database for file search that is managed by the kpathsea set of tools. It requires a specific command to refresh the database. Try running `sudo texhash`

BTW, `subfigure` is no longer maintained and is considered as deprecated. From ctan subfigure page:

> The pack­age is now con­sid­ered ob­so­lete: it was su­per­seded by sub­fig, but users may find the more re­cent sub­cap­tion pack­age more sat­is­fac­tory.

For a new document, I would advice you to switch to another package.